# Deepstack ensemble import error in google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, importerror

I am trying to import StackEnsemble from deepstack in google colab, but I am getting an import error.

I have installed deepstack, and the import of KerasMember works fine but importing the ensemble just does not work:

```
from deepstack.ensemble import StackEnsemble
```

Here is the full error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input> in <module>()
----> 1 from deepstack.ensemble import StackEnsemble
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/deepstack/ensemble.py in <module>()
     11 import glob
     12 from deepstack.base import Member
---> 13 from keras.utils import to_categorical
     14 
     15 
ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?